# Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module" by skype in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: gtk3, shared-library

When i run skype from terminal this message appear, but skype run successfully. I have checked that unity-gtk-module is installed in my system and required lib files are available but in 64 environment. There is not package named unity-gtk-module:i386. I have created a soft link of appropriate lib to /usr/lib but skype return **ELF Class** error (not 32bit lib). I also set GTK_PATH but still not working. How to install 32bit version of library for unity-gtk-module?

```
export GTK_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/
```

Answer (score 1):

Skype 4.2.0.11 was working (I had the noise problem , if somebody tried to call me , than all I heard was a long buzz, which stopped only if I shut Skype down)

I wanted to upgrade to Skype 4.2.0.13 downloaded from Skype.com the ~ skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.13-1_i386.deb ~

I removed the old skype with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge skype
```

I run the

```
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.13-1_i386.deb
```

then I tried to run

```
skype
```

Then this shows up:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

Now skype wont even start.
Any ideas?

Thank you